# My SDL Program suddenly stops. I don't know why

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

#define COL(x, y) (bool)*((int*)screen->pixels + (screen->w * y * 4) + (x * 4))
#define RESULT_SIZE 1260000

#define WIDTH 110

#define HEIGHT 120

int main(){
    SDL_Event event;
    printf("[....] Initialize SDL\r");
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    printf("[ ok ] Initialize SDL\n");
    printf("[....] Initialize Window\r");
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(110, 120, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
    printf("[ ok ] Initialize Window\n");
    printf("[....] Load font bmp\r");
    SDL_Surface* image = SDL_LoadBMP("./font.bmp");
    printf("[ ok ] Load font bmp\n");

    printf("[....] Draw\r");
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screen, NULL);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    printf("[ ok ] Draw\n");

    //Export 10*10 fonts to file
    printf("[info] Export as binary file...\n");
    printf("[....] Open result file...\r");
    FILE* out = fopen("font.pb", "w");
    if(out == NULL){
        perror("[FAIL] Open result file... Failed!");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("[ ok ] Open result file...\n");
    printf("Writing... Please wait...\n");
    printf("______________________________\r");
    int write = 0;
    for(int startY = 0; startY < HEIGHT; startY += 10)
        for(int startX = 0; startX < WIDTH; startX += 10)
            for(int x = startX; x < startX + 10; x++){
                int y;
                for(y = startY; y < startY + 10; y++){
                    float p = (((float)write/(float)RESULT_SIZE)*100)/2;    
                    int bar = (int) p;
                    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) if(i < p) printf("="); else printf("_");
                    if(write < 1024)
                    printf(" %dB/1230K\r", write);
                    else{
                        float kb = write / 1024;
                        printf(" %dK/1230K\r", (int) kb);
                    }
                    printf("sx: %d sy: %d x: %d y: %d c: %d---", startX, startY, x, y, COL(x, y));
                    fputc(COL(x, y), out);
                    printf("ok\n");
                    write++;
                }
                y = 0;
            }
    fclose(out);
    printf("\nDone.");
}
```

This is source code. This program loads bitmap file using SDL.
In bitmap, there's 10*10 fonts.

When bitmap is loaded, this copies each 10*10 pixel to file.
(like this:
Bitmap:
BBBBBBBBBBWWW....
BWBWBWBWBW
BWBWBWBWBW
BWBWBWBWBW
BWBWBWBWBW
BWBWBWBWBW
BWBWBWBWBW
BWBWBWBWBW
BWBWBWBWBW
BWBWBWBWBW

File:
11111111111010101010.....1010111
)

But result of this program is...

```
...
sx: 50 sy: 30 x: 59 y: 35 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 50 sy: 30 x: 59 y: 36 c: 1---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 50 sy: 30 x: 59 y: 37 c: 1---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 50 sy: 30 x: 59 y: 38 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 50 sy: 30 x: 59 y: 39 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 30 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 31 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 32 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 33 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 34 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 35 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 36 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 37 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 38 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 60 y: 39 c: 1---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 61 y: 30 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 61 y: 31 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 61 y: 32 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 61 y: 33 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 61 y: 34 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
sx: 60 sy: 30 x: 61 y: 35 c: 0---ok_______________ 3K/1230K
...
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 108 y: 34 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 108 y: 35 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 108 y: 36 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 108 y: 37 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 108 y: 38 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 108 y: 39 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 30 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 31 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 32 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 33 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 34 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 35 c: 1---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 36 c: 1---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 37 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 38 c: 1---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 39 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 40 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 41 c: 1---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 42 c: 1---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 43 c: 1---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 44 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**
next line maybe..(It couldn't shown because of error)
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 45 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
```

Before this error, it worked well.(BMP File is shown)
I think the error is caused by

**(bool)*((int*)screen->pixels + (screen->w * y * 4) + (x * 4))**
**EDIT: "*4" is... Each pixel is 4 bytes. so for correct address, need *4**

I also checked with gdb. It stops on line using this.
I checked memory address, but it was not.
X and Y was correct and it's inside window.

Why it stopped?

EDIT

I tried -g option on g++(for debugging)
And it's result is

```
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 35 c: 1---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 36 c: 1---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 37 c: 0---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 38 c: 1---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 100 sy: 30 x: 109 y: 39 c: 1---ok_____________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 40 c: 1---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 41 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 42 c: 1---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 43 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 44 c: 1---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 45 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 46 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 47 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K
sx: 0 sy: 40 x: 0 y: 48 c: 0---ok_________________ 4K/1230K

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400def in main () at bitmap.cpp:61
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
61                      printf("sx: %d sy: %d x: %d y: %d c: %d---", startX, startY, x, y, COL(x, y));
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400def in main () at bitmap.cpp:61
(gdb)
```

As you can see, the error is caused by using getting Pixel.(COL(x, y))

Comment: A "segmentation fault" is your program crashing. most likely because of a pointer error. Build your program with debug information (add the `-g` flag to gcc) and run your program in a debugger. The debugger will stop when the crash happens, and let you examine the function call stack. Walk up the function call stack to your code and you can examine the values of variables. If nothing else, please post the function call-stack when the crash happens (the GDB command `bt`).

Comment: What do you expect the `* 4`s up there to be doing?

Comment: Because video memory's structure is... r g b a r g b a.... It is 4 bytes. So, for correct address, it need *4

Comment: oh no... I thought one more about *4.. Variable type is int..(it is 4 bytes!) 4*4 is 8 bytes. Now it works!

Comment: 4*4 = 8? :) Also, you need to lock the surface before you access `pixels`.